# Combine duplicate questions in search results

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, search

I often see questions asked and they are flagged as duplicate by the moderator which is great.

The issue is; when doing a search for a question I see a list of answers that are actually duplicates and have already been flagged as such by the moderators.  Is there any way in the search results to combine these under a single header/result so as to make searching more effective.

Comment: An old questions, but just wanted to ask the same. Apparently it's not really a problem for most.